# Apply `torch.nn.MultiheadAttention`’s heads to same input

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, attention-model

My question surely has a simple answer, but I couldn't find it. I wish to apply `MultiheadAttention` to the same sequence without copying the sequence. My data is temporal data with dimensions (batch, time, channels). I treat the "channels" dimension as the embedding, and the time dimension as the sequence dimension. For example:

```py
N, C, T = 2, 3, 5
n_heads = 7
X = torch.rand(N, T, C)
```

Now, I want to apply 7 different heads as self-attention to the same input `X`, but as far as I understand, it attrequires me to copy the data 7 times:

```py
attn = torch.nn.MultiheadAttention(C * n_heads, n_heads, batch_first=True)
X_ = X.repeat(1, 1, n_heads)
attn(X_, X_, X_)
```

Is there any way to do this without copying the data 7 times?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use the ```Linear``` layer to project features/embeddings into ```C*n_heads``` space before feeding it into MHA. Or if ```C``` is large enough you can directly feed it into ```MHA(C, n_heads)``` layer given ```C%n_heads == 0```.

Comment: @GirishHegde The first option is likely less efficient than simply `X.repeat`, and the second will slice the channels/embeddings into groups.

Comment: ```x.repeat``` is little(only a single ```Linear``` layer is **not** that expensive) efficient computation-wise, but I think projection onto higher space makes more sense. And  ```MHA``` **doesn't slice** embeddings into groups, it **projects** embeddings onto smaller ```emb/heads``` space